# Why is Gradle looking in the wrong place for my plugin?

Tags: gradle, plugins, classpath

At the top of my build.gradle file I put this:

```
buildscript
{
    repositories 
    {
        mavenLocal()
    }
    dependencies
    {
        classpath(group: 'com.telenav.tdk.core.gradle', name: 'tdk-core-gradle-plugin', version: '1.0')
    }
}
```

Below I try to apply the plugin, but it doesn't matter because it's not looking in the local maven repo for the right artifact. I get this error instead:

```
* What went wrong:
Plugin [id: 'tdk-core-gradle-plugin', version: '1.0'] was not found in any of the following sources:

- Gradle Core Plugins (not a core plugin, please see https://docs.gradle.org/6.5.1/userguide/standard_plugins.html for available core plugins)
- Plugin Repositories (could not resolve plugin artifact 'tdk-core-gradle-plugin:tdk-core-gradle-plugin.gradle.plugin:1.0')
  Searched in the following repositories:
    Gradle Central Plugin Repository
```

I find this strange because (1) it didn't search my local maven repository and (2) it looked from a completely different artifact descriptor:

```
'tdk-core-gradle-plugin:tdk-core-gradle-plugin.gradle.plugin:1.0
```

than the one I explicitly specified:

```
com.telenav.tdk.core.gradle:tdk-core-gradle-plugin:1.0
```

This is pretty counter-intuitive to me, but I'm sure there's some kind of explanation.
Anyone have any idea what's going on?

Thanks,

```
Jon
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Plugin repositories - see how to set the same
   https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/plugins.html#sec:plugin_management

   settings.gradle

   pluginManagement {
   repositories {
   }
   }
2. there are 2 ways to apply plugin & resolution differs, see for details

DSL https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/plugins.html#sec:plugin_markers
buildscript https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/plugins.html#sec:old_plugin_application

Comment: This was very helpful. Thanks!